# Structures in matlab: save load and work

Tags: matlab, structure

I am trying to work with structures in matlab. I have a code which looks like this :

```
for i=1:10
    a(i).p=some value;
    a(i).q=some other value
end
```

I saved it to a mat file, but it didn't seem successful. Can anyone tell me, how do I save and load this structure to a file/from a file and read a particular type of data? for example, how can I read the field `a(i).q` after loading the structure?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For saving and loading use [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) and [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html):

```
for ii=1:10
    a(ii).p = rand(1);
    a(ii).q = rand(1);
end
save( 'myMatFile.mat', 'a' ); % note that the variable name is passed as a STRING

clear a; % remove a from workspace. it is gone...
exist( 'a', 'var' ), % make sure a is gone

load( 'myMatFile.mat' ); % load 
exist( 'a', 'var' ), % a now exists! Ta-da!!

a(5).q, % access the fifth element of a
```

PS
[It is best not to use `i` and `j` as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: Just be aware that MATLAB can't handle  `save('file.mat','a.p')` . You need to do `foo=a.p; save('file.mat','foo')`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you can `save('file.mat','a','-struct')` to get the variable `p` in the saved file.

Comment: Well, yes,  `save('file.mat',-struct,'a','p')` will work, but why should the user have to do what the parser should handle?